# Create a table with a given name?

Tags: lua

I don't really understand why this doesn't create a table using a given name. Can someone help clarify this for me?

```
local table={}

local function createtable(tabname, propername)
    table.tabname={}
    table.tabname.propername=propername or "need a proper name"
end

createtable(foo, "first table")
createtable(bar, "second table")

for k,v in pairs(table) do
    print("table name: "..k)
end
```

Output:

```
table name: tabname
```

Why doesn't it use the given variable value in the function call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You meant `tab[tabname]={}` not `tab.tabname={}`.

The `tab.str` syntax treats the bit after `.` as a string key not a variable.

Also don't use `table` as a table name. You shadow the default `table` library.

Also in `createtable(foo, "first table")` unless the `foo` variable already exists that is equivalent to `createtable(nil, "first table")`. Did you mean `createtable("foo", "first table")`?

Comment: Ohhh it's working now. I swear I tried that earlier but it still gave a "attempt to call a nil value" error. I guess I didn't change a line that referenced that table's values.

And yeah I never use the key "table". I was just giving it a generic name.

Cheers, bud.